# Fetching Large Data to render on Datatable - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of 20,000 rows in my database that I am fetching to my table. I have this 20,000 rows stored to a localStorage to improve speed. My issue is, when I am navigating to the page (which contains the 20,000 rows), it lags for few seconds before the page is loaded.

How can I let my page render and wait for the huge data to be fetched ?

PS: `getItem function fetches the data and store in array items and stored to localStorage.setItem('my_items')` .

**Index.js**

```
 state: {
     items:[],
     loading:true;
   }

componentDidMount()
{       

let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_items'));

if(items)
    {
      this.setState({
      items: items
    })      
     this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
    else
    {
        this.getItems();
    }
}





  return (

{loading &&
           <div className="d-flex justify-content-center loader-overlay">
              <CircularProgress />
           </div>
        }

       <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.getMuiTheme()}>

                <MUIDataTable

                    title={
                    }
                    data={this.state.items.map(item => {
                        return [
                           item.name,
                           item.type
                        ]

                     })}
                    columns={columns}
                    options={options}
                        />
            </MuiThemeProvider>   
        );
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing pagination?

Comment: @AZ_, server side pagination ??  I am using data tables. So the data is already paginated on the table

Comment: I meant implement pagination when you are fetching the data from the table, `already paginated in the table` you mean sorted?

Comment: @Switz datatables comes with pagination, sorting. you should implement server-side processing: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: @AZ_, how is the pagination done on the client side for large data? I may not be aware of how that is implemented. But yes, the data is paginated and sorted already

Comment: In terms of UX why would you want to load 20k rows in the first place? What would be the reason behind this? Maybe implement progressive loading (say with `useEffect`) as the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: ohh ok, thanks @peter I don't know much about datatables.

Comment: I suggest you look into server-side pagination.

Comment: You shouldn't be retrieving all 20k records in one go. Retrieve limited records suitable per page with pagination. Instead of one API call you will have multiple calls with each pagination click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is usually solved by using server side pagination. It should work something like this:

1. Open page with data table and you fetch first 20 items (or whatever size of a page is). You send `/api/tableData?offset=0&limit=20`. This will only return first 20 items.
2. User clicks on next page, you fetch the second page using `/api/tableData?offset=20&limit=20`. This will return items with id 21-40.
3. User clicks on next page, you fetch the third page using `/api/tableData?offset=20&limit=20`

If you are using `mui-datatables` NPM package, it has option `serverSide` and it helps you to do it easily. Chjeck `Remote Data` section in the documentation of MUI datatables package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables#remote-data.

But if you are sure about your use case and you don't want to do server side pagination, you can use `Web Worker`. The problem in your application is that `JSON.parse` for such a huge collection takes way too long. With `Web Worker`, you can start another thread that will not block the UI thread. In the worker thread, you will start parsing the collection and when you finish parsing, you will send the data back to the UI thread. Web workers were designed for exactly this use case. You can learn about it more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: With this method, when the user is searching for an item, the search will be limited

Comment: If you want to use filtering, you should also do it server side. So the API call would change to something like `/api/tableData?offset=0&limit=20&search=foo&search-column=name` if you want to only have first 20 items that contain name `foo`. This is just an example, you can implement it however you like, but the principle is always the same. Do sorting, filtering and pagination on the server (if you are using mysql, you will use limit, offset and order by).